# gstreamer ubuntu gscam How to separate my camra left and right images

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer, ros, slam

This is my camera picture:

[image: click here to see my camera picture]

My camera is special (Not a pure binocular camera), has one usb interface but two device numbersthe.
 device:/dev/video0 is about left and right camera images, 
device:/dev/video1 is the depth of the image combined with left and right cameras, I used gscam (gstream) driven out / dev / video0 is this case:The left and right camera images are in a window inside:

[image: click here to see driven out picture]

How to separate them? divided into two windows, let the left and right camera images are displayed separately?

Comment: this is my driven code:v4l2src device=$(arg DEVICE) ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=$(arg FPS) ! ffmpegcolorspace

Comment: What is the captured video dimensions (width x height)?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use a tee and two videocrop elements to cut out the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided is next. Using a `width=1280, height=480` **videotestsrc** the cropping could be done using `videocrop` plugin and a `tee`.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=0 ! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=480 ! tee name=t ! videocrop left=640 ! queue ! ximagesink t. ! videocrop right=640 ! queue ! ximagesink
```

In gstreamer 0.10, the pipeline would be next:

```
gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc pattern=0 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width=1280, height=480 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! tee name="t" ! videocrop left=640 ! queue ! ximagesink t. ! videocrop right=640 ! queue ! ximagesink
```

The original source is the SMPTE color bars from the videotestsrc. The resulting crop is shown in the next [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCQ2i.png). Adjusting it to your needs, you should have your two separated video images.